# Error executing SSIS Package

Tags: dll, ssis, console, global

I am running MS SQL Server on Window 8. SSIS Package is giving the error below:

```
SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me whether you are running this in BIDS or as part of a job.  The likely problem is related to permissions under SQL Agent vs. BIDS.  If you are only seeing this error in a job, then it is likely related to the permissions of the account applied by the service.  Take a look at the following link for assistance in resolving:

http://saveadba.blogspot.com/2012/02/could-not-open-global-shared-memory-to.html